# how to append drop down options inside render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tsx

below is my code. `console.log` of `this.Resources` result is shown below

1:"Basavaraj"
2:"Ashuthosh"
3:"Sravan"
4:"Raghavendra"
5:"Prem kumar"
6:"Simran"
7:"Namratha"
8:"Ghanashri"
9:"Ravindra"
10:"Anand"
11:"Shaeen"

```
render() {

 console.log(this.Resources);
 const options = this.Resources.map((item, index) =>{
 <option key={index} value={item}>{item}</option>
 });

  return (
    <div>
    <form>
    <div id="select">
    <div className="container select">
    <div  className="row">
      <select  className="col-4 selectpicker input-large">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select resouce</option>
        {options}
      </select>
```

I want all data in `this.Resources` should come in `select` drop down options.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning the html in map.Need to return it.

```
const options = this
  .Resources
  .map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <option key={index} value={item}>{item}</option>
    );
  });
```

OR

ECMA6 arrow notation with default return:

```
const options = this
  .Resources
  .map((item, index) => (
    <option key={index} value={item}>{item}</option>
  ));
```

Comment: the difference between two of above is only of curly braces..??

Comment: @MukulSharma yes, ES6 arrow functions, 2 forms of it